# Usage of 长短 vs 长度

Tags: meaning, usage

Based in the dictionary, 长短 = length and 长度 = length. What is the usage or difference between the two words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both 长短 and 长度 mean 'length'

长短 is mostly used colloquially; 长度 is more common in both literary and colloquial form

> When in smaller scale, the two terms are interchangeable.
>
> For example: 剑的**长短**通常是70-110厘米 = 剑的**长度**通常是70-110厘米 (The length of a sword is usually 70-110 cm)
>
> *When something can be short or long, using 长短 should be safe, e.g. 路线的长短不一 (the length of routes vary)*
>
> but using 长度 is the safest: 路线的长短不一 = 路线的长度不一*

~

> When in larger scale, we only use 长度
>
> For example: 泰坦尼克号的**长度**是269米 (length of Titanic is 269 m)
>
> *We don't say 泰坦尼克号的长短是269米*
>
> *ships like Titanic can never be described as short*

*长短 can also be a shortened form  of '长处短处' (strengths and weaknesses); 说人长短 means "criticize someone"*